# IE ,window.open has to open different webpages of same domain in different windows

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, window.open, new-window

I have html page say abc.htm it has 2 anchors which are pointing to link1.htm and link2.htm. code looks like this[image]

Now my requirement is when i click on GOTOLink1 new window has to be opend with link1.htm.
Without closing this,now am clicking on GOTOLink2, it has to open link2.htm in new window without disturbing first window.
 Now 3 windows are open , If I click on GOTOLink1 it has to focus the existing window(no new window has to be opened), same for GOTOLink2 also.
    Finally , my major requiremnet is 
    1.New window has to be opened if not exist 
    2.If window exists it has to focus the existing window.
IE is failing for above 2 features. FF is sucess in feature 1 only. 
Please help me. I need the compatabity for IE,FF,Crome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the distict windowName instead of null.
EX:

function(url,distictName)
{
 Window.Open(URL, distictName, "location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=1000,height=700,resizable=yes");
}